# How to receive a notification when two bodies do not make contact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In `DidBeginContact` I like to be notified when two bodies do not make contact.

I tried using the `!(NOT)` operator, but it didn't work.

```
if (!(firstBody.categoryBitMask == kBrickCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == kCarCategory)) {
    NSLog(@"Hit");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didBeginContact` only gets called when a collision happens. You set a `Bool` in `update` to `false` and set it `true` in `didBeginContact` if there was a collision. Check it in `didFinishUpdate` and take action accordingly.

Sample code is in Swift but should be easy to convert to Objective-C.

```
class MyScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var contactMadeThisFrame = false

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        contactMadeThisFrame = false
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == kBrickCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == kCarCategory {
            contactMadeThisFrame = true
        }
    }

    override func didFinishUpdate() {
        if !contactMadeThisFrame {
            print("Hit")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to check on a per node basis (take actions only on nodes that did not make contact), then you can iterate through the bodies and check if `physicsBody.allContactedBodies` count is zero. Do this in `didFinishUpdate`.